# Error detection, suggestions and auto-completion seems not to work in Netbeans 8.2, why?

Tags: git, jsp, netbeans-8

Since pushing my web project (written in jsp created using netbeans 8.2) to git, netbeans seems not detecting errors, giving suggestions or autocompleting my code anymore. But when i copy files from the project and paste them to a new created web project; Error detection, suggestions and auto-completion work for some time, until I restart the IDE, it stops to working again. What's the problem and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Netbeans 8.0.2 and used my project it. My problem is now fixed.